# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined

Tags: java, android, google-text-to-speech

I would like to use Google Text-to-Speech but I get the following error:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials
> are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute
> Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable
> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file
> defining the credentials. See
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
> for more information.

I do not understand this, since I have already defined that environment variable. See here:

[image]

I have also logged in with `gcloud auth application-default login`.

Why do I get this error?

### Update

This is what happens if I try to log in:

> C:\Users\rsaad\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth application-default login
>
> The environment variable [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS] is set to:
> [C:\Users\rsaad\AndroidStudioProjects\Kitt\Kitt-0a9a71966cc8.json]
> Credentials will still be generated to the default location:
> [C:\Users\rsaad\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentia
> ls.json] To use these credentials, unset this environment variable
> before running your application.
>
> Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y
>
> Your browser has been opened to visit:
>
> ```
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=764086051850-6qr4p6gpi6hn506pt8ejuq83di341hur.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&code_challenge=xgtC_woosyFMJXQk6sVWDFqJew9jBAKDEABK_cxEVqc&code_challenge_method=S256&access_type=offline&response_type=code&prompt=select_account
> ```
>
> Credentials saved to file:
> [C:\Users\rsaad\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json]
>
> These credentials will be used by any library that requests
> Application Default Credentials (ADC).
> C:\Users\rsaad\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud
> SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\third_party\google\auth_default.py:69:
> UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user
> credentials from Google Cloud SDK without a quota project. You might
> receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. We recommend
> you rerun `gcloud auth application-default login` and make sure a
> quota project is added. Or you can use service accounts instead. For
> more information about service accounts, see
> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
> warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
>
> Quota project "kitt-292122" was added to ADC which can be used by
> Google client libraries for billing and quota. Note that some services
> may still bill the project owning the resource.

Comment: I am assuming this is not complaining about your machine's environment variable. You might put the variable in your application environment file. Based on the framework that you are using, the env files might be different. I would recommend searching that env file in your project and put the credentials path there under `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` name.

Comment: @ReazMurshed thanks, that could be correct. I have updated my question.